# How to converted timestamp string to a date in java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a string "1427241600000" and I want it converted to "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

I have tried, but I am not able to parse it, please review the below code

```
try {
    String str = "1427241600000";
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date =sf.parse(str);
    System.out.println(date);       
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would like to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Or you can use java.sql.Timestamp.

Answer (score 18):

You should try it the other way around. First get the Date out of the milliTime and then format it.

```
String str = "1427241600000";
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str));
System.out.println(sf.format(date));
```

Comment: I suggest `parseLong` instead of `valueOf` as you need a `long` rather than a `Long`

Answer (score 4):

the conversion is highly dependent on what format the timestamp is in. But i assume the whole thing should actually be a `long` and is simply the systemtime from when the timestamp was created. So this should work:

```
String str = ...;
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Date date =new Date(Long.parseLong(str));` to convert your String to Date object.

if you are using `SimpleDateFormat()` the format specified as a parameter to this function should match the format of the date in the String (str in your case). In your case `yyyy-MM-dd` does not match the format of the time stamp (1427241600000).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

use a SimpleDateFormat with an appropriate format string (be careful to use the correct format letters, uppercase and lowercase have different meanings!).

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");
Date date = format.parse("022310141505");
```